# when or before sounds better

Tags: grammar

> He had had a house when he met her.

I think the sentence sounds fine and grammatically correct.

I think the sentence below sounds a little bit unnatural with the when clause.

> He had bought a house [ when / before ] he met her.

Which of the two, when or before, sounds more grammatically correct?  Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Comment: We'd probably say "He had **already** bought a house when|before he met her." or "He **already** owned a house when|before he met her."

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaking grammar, meaning, and usage.

Your first sentence may **possibly** be grammatical, but it is hard to imagine a situation that would be described by a native speaker with that sentence.

If the meaning to be conveyed is that A owned a house at the time when he met B, that meaning would be expressed as

**A owned a house when he met B** or, less exactly, **A had a house when he met B.**

If the meaning to be conveyed is that A did not own a house when he met B despite having previously owned one, your sentence might be grammatical, but a native speaker of US English would use something like

**A did not own a house when he met B although he had owned one years before.**

The point is that **when** is used in such constructions to link contemporaneous situations. Using tense to modify the normal meaning of **when** may not violate any rule of grammar, but is far from idiomatic in the US.